# Best Practices for JDBC/database unit testing

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, jdbc, junit

I have code which talks to multiple database like Sybase, Postgress, DB2 etc. So I have different modules with different queries for each of these databases. I started with H2 and JUnit to do unit testing. Since Sybase, Postgres, DB2 etc queries don't work in H2, I started transforming my existing target queries into a format which H2 can accept and I found that many SQL functions like RANK(), partition, complex join updates, case when etc are not supported or don’t work as expected in H2. How do I go about unit testing this code?

Should I unit test each db module with corresponding databases?
For example, will the Sybase module have unit tests which will talk to Sybase instead of H2, or do I have to use H2 if I unit-test my database code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should test each of your database-specific query modules against a real instance of the database it is written for. By some definitions this is integration testing but not unit testing, but so what -- you need the tests regardless of what they're called.

Write the unit tests of the rest of your code to be real unit tests, stubbing out the database modules, so those tests don't require any running database and don't come to depend on the quirks of any one database that you support.

Set up most of your acceptance or integration tests to run against your favorite database that you actually support, one that every developer has on their machine. You will learn things about that database that you would not have learned if you were using a special database only for tests. Have at least one integration test (some basic use case in your app) that exercises each database module.

Organize your unit and integration tests so that you can run all of the tests except the ones that require specific database modules (but including the ones that run against your favorite). Set up a continuous integration system to run ALL the tests, so that bugs in less-used database modules aren't missed.